# How to calculate percentage of uses with condition in sql oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a table that looks a bit like this.

| Type | Number |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 0 |
| a | 1 |
| a | 1 |
| b | 0 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 1 |

I need to calculate percentage of zeros for each type that are more than 10%. So the result has to look like this:

| Type | Percentage of 0 |
| --- | --- |
| a | 25 |
| b | 50 |

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT type,
       COUNT(CASE value WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) * 100 AS percentage_of_0
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY type
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (type, value) AS
SELECT 'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| TYPE | PERCENTAGE_OF_0 |
| --- | --- |
| b | 50 |
| c | 0 |
| a | 25 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0E-ZeTOP)

Answer (score 1):

If `0` and `1` are the only two possible values, you can use aggregation and arithmetics like so:

```
select type, avg(1 - number) * 100 as percentage_of_0s
from mytable t
group by type
```

If there are more possible values and you want the percent of `0` values, then I would recommend `avg()` and a `case` expression:

```
select type, 
    avg(case when number = 0 then 100 else 0 end) as percentage_of_0s
from mytable t
group by type
```